# PyQt5 - Detecting mouse clicks outside of window

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouseevent, mouse

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to make a program using PyQt5 that detects mouse click events that are outside of the program window. I was unable to find anything online, is there any way of do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't do that I think.  You can however detect when the program isn't in the foreground

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I'll try doing the fullscreen.

Answer (score -3):

Easy: Make your program fullscreen.